# In the collapse panel all elements simultaneously react to the click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, event-handling, accordion

In  my app, I have an array of the items in which each item has a title and additional info.
To display the info I want to make each item collapsible (toggle when clicked).
But now, when I click on one item the other items also respond, because each item listens to the state.

How can I make this event listen only item that I click on?

For simplicity I've reduced my object to 3 items but in fact my json file is large and for this reason I use the map method

```js
// my profiles.json
let profiles = [{"name":"John", "count": 2}, {"name":"Kitty", "count": 3}, {"name":"Ji", "count": 4}]

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.profiles,
      open: false,
      expand: 'close'
    }
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.open) {
      this.setState({ open: false, expand: 'close' })
    } else {
      this.setState({ open: true, expand: 'open' })
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    let { data } = this.state
    const listItem = data.map((profile, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index} >
          <div className='profile-title' onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
            <span className='name'>{profile.name}</span> 
          </div>
          <div className={`profile-content ${this.state.expand}`}>
            <span className='number'>{profile.count}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div className='content'>
          { listItem }
      </div>
    )
  } 
}


const App = () => (
  <div><Main profiles={profiles} /></div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.close {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
.open {
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.profile-title{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Samuel Kwak said you should consider using a Component Library for doing such things.

E.g. I personally like [BlueprintJS](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v2/#blueprint), which provides a component called Collapse:

```js
export class CollapseExample extends React.Component<{}, ICollapseExampleState> {
public state = {
    isOpen: false,
};
 
public render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                {this.state.isOpen ? "Hide" : "Show"} build logs
            </Button>
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
                <pre>
                    Dummy text.
                </pre>
            </Collapse>
        </div>
    );
}
 
private handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
}
}
```

Copied from [here](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v2/#core/components/collapse)

Another great Component is provided by Material-UI. You can find a demo [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/expansion-panels/).